# pan, zoom, and move for geom_sf_interactive in ggiraph

Tags: r, ggiraph

Is there a way to pan, zoom and move a map created with `geom_sf_interactive`?
The demo of the package ggiraphExtra has zoomable and movable maps created with `ggChoropleth` in the intro doc at
http://rpubs.com/cardiomoon/231820
but I have not been able to reproduce this.
Additionally, ggiraphExtra doe not adhere to ggplot syntax and it seems not to work with sf maps.

If `geom_sf_interactive` cannot do this, ist it worthwhile being considered as a feature to be added. Perhaps not only fpor geom_sf_interactive but also for other geoms?

Comment: pan and zoom is available for all output generated by `ggiraph::girafe`. see the documentation here: https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/articles/offcran/customizing.html#zoom and here https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/reference/geom_sf_interactive.html

Comment: Meanwhile, I found opts_zoom.   Thank you.